# Description of ideals of ring $F[x]/(x^n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

What is a description of the ideals of the ring $F[x]/(x^n)$, where $F$ is a field?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You can pull back ideals from the quotient to $F[x]$, and so you can convert the problem to classifying ideals of $F[x]$ that contain $(x^n)$.

Comment: Since I have gotten no feedback from the original poster, I want to add a second hint: $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain and a PID.

Answer (score 4):

By the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem, there is a 1-1 correspondence between ideals in $F[x]$ containing $(x^n)$ and ideals in $F[x] / (x^n)$. So you are reduced to considering ideals $I \subseteq F[x]$ that contain $(x^n)$, i.e. $(x^n) \subseteq I$.

Now, $F$ is a field so $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. In particular, it is a PID. Thus $I = (p(x))$ for some $p(x) \in F[x]$. Then $(x^n) \subseteq (p(x))$ if and only if $p(x) \mid x^n$ if and only if $p(x) = cx^d$ for some integer d satisfying $0 \le d \le n$ and $c \in F^*$.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that since ideals generated by different polynomials can be the same ideal, you get that the only ideals are $(x^d)$ (so in particular, the list of ideals is finite).

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the quotient ring and t be the image of x in A. Then A is isomorphic to F[t]. Since A/(t) is isomorphic to F, which is a field, (t) is of course a maximal ideal of A. But it is actually the only one, because any element outside (t) is invertible: up to a non zero multiplicative constant, any such element can be written 1 + tz, which has an inverse because t is nilpotent (think of the formal inverse of 1 + tz). So the strict ideals of A are the principal ideals (t^k), k between 1 and n.

PS. After writing this, I realize that it's exactly Geoff Robinson's answer, under a slightly different guise !

Comment: Don't worry if you recreate someone else's argument. This site is very much about teaching and learning, so small differences in presentation can be important. You never know what small thing might trip up a reader.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to proceed directly by determining the structure of the ring $R = F[x]/(x^{n})$. Note that when $n =1,$ the quotient ring is just $F$ itself.
In general, by the Euclidean property of polynomial rings (over fields), 
every element of $R$ has a unique expression in the form $a_{0} + a_{1}y + \ldots + a_{n-1}y^{n-1}$, where $y$ is the element $x + (x^{n})$ in $R$. The product of such elements is easily described, determined by the rule $y^{i}.y^{j} = 0$ if $i+j \geq n$.

An element $a_{0} + a_{1}y + \ldots + a_{n-1}y^{n-1}$ is a unit of $R$ if and only if $a_{0} \neq 0$ ( I omit details, but it is consequence of the Euclidean algorithm for $F[x]$).

Thus every proper non-zero ideal of $R$ is contained in $(y)$. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ (proper and non-zero), and choose $i$ maximal such that $I \subseteq (y^{i})$ but $I \not \subseteq (y^{i+1})$. Then $I$ contains an element of the from $y^{i}(a_{0} + \ldots a_{n-1-i}y^{n-1-i})$ with $a_{0} \neq 0$. Since $(a_{0} + \ldots a_{n-1-i}y^{n-1-i})$ is a unit of $R$, we see that 
$(y^{i}) \subseteq I$, so that $I = (y^{i})$.

Hence the ideals of $R$ are 
$0 \subset (y^{n-1}) \subset (y^{n-2}) \subset\ldots \subset (y^{2}) \subset (y) \subset R$,
(and all inclusions are strict).